# Powershell: how to "grep" the output of a command by using "select-string"?

Tags: powershell

When I issue `get-service` command, I get the entire list of services.

I want to list only a specific service.

The service in question is being listed in the output of `get-service`:

```
Running  nginx              nginx
```

But if I try to use any of the following:

```
PS C:\Users\x> get-service | Select-String "nginx"
PS C:\Users\x> get-service | Select-String -Pattern "nginx"
PS C:\Users\x> get-service | Select-String -Pattern 'nginx'
```

I get no output.

So how do I "grep" in Powershell?

Comment: try select-object, as get-service return isn't returning string but object, try `get-service | select-object Status,Name | select-string nginx`, I don't know how to prettify it, but I think you can try to add other or flatten the result.

Comment: why do you use `Select-String` when `Get-Service` already has many filtering options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
Get-Service -Name "nginx"
```

Answer (score 4):

An essential thing to note is that PowerShell cmdlets *always* output *objects*, not simple strings - even when the output seems to be a string, it is really a [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) object.  You can check the type of the output of a command (and the associated properties and methods) using [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.1):

```
Get-Service | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

Name                      MemberType    Definition
----                      ----------    ----------
Name                      AliasProperty Name = ServiceName
RequiredServices          AliasProperty RequiredServices = ServicesDependedOn
Disposed                  Event         System.EventHandler Disposed(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
Close                     Method        void Close()
Continue                  Method        void Continue()
...
```

As mentioned by others, `Get-Service` (and other cmdlets) has built-in filtering for what you're trying to do, but a more general alternative, which is more flexible (though often slower) is [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1):

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 's*' -and $_.Status -eq 'Running'}

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  SamSs              Security Accounts Manager
Running  SCardSvr           Smart Card
Running  Schedule           Task Scheduler
Running  SecurityHealthS... Windows Security Service
Running  SENS               System Event Notification Service
...
```